# writing a rspec test for checking a function that returns a hash table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Trying to write an RSpec test that checks a function `location_counts(piece)` that returns a hash table with some keys and values assigned.

```
 describe "location_counts(piece)" do
   it "should return a hash table with a key of locations and value of times visited" do
     game = FactoryGirl.create(:game)
     black_queen = FactoryGirl.create(:queen, game_id: game.id, row: 8, column: 4, is_black: true)

     black_queen.move_to(4,4)
     black_queen.move_to(1,1)
     black_queen.move_to(4,4)

   expect(game.location_counts(black_queen)).to be {"4, 4"=>2, "1, 1"=>1}
  end
end
```

With this test, I'm getting a syntax error. 
That looks like:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in `load': /home/ubuntu/workspace/chess-app/spec/models/game_spec.rb:101: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}' (SyntaxError)
...s(black_queen)).to be {"4, 4"=>2, "1, 1"=>1} 
...                               ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/chess-app/spec/models/game_spec.rb:101: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
...en)).to be {"4, 4"=>2, "1, 1"=>1} 
...                               ^
```

Comment: Could you give the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that ruby is interpreting your expected hash:

```
expect(game.location_counts(black_queen)).to be {"4, 4"=>2, "1, 1"=>1}
```

as a block passed to the `be` method, instead of as a parameter. Try the following:

```
expect(game.location_counts(black_queen)).to eq({"4, 4"=>2, "1, 1"=>1})
```

or even removing the curly braces, as the hash is the last parameter passed to the `be` method:

```
expect(game.location_counts(black_queen)).to eq("4, 4"=>2, "1, 1"=>1)
```

**EDIT**: Regard the usage of `eq` instead of `be`.

Comment: Thanks! Although it didn't directly solve my problem, it did help. I eventually had to use `eq({"4, 4"=>2, "1, 1"=>1})`. The error message I got after I added the parentheses was that the object identity was not the same, so I had to change it to `eq()`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will update the answer to help others with the same problem in the future